# How can I query against a concatenated field?

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I would like to search for a first name and surname in two sql fields using entity framework. Below is some example code where I am searching for searchString as a concatenation of firstname and lastname database strings.

```
using(var ent = new testEntities)
{
    ent.Contacts.Where(u => (u.firstname + ' ' + u.lastname).contains(searchString))
}
```

Searching a single field is easy but how could I query for a string which is a concatenation of two database fields.

Comment: Do you get any errors when you try your code?

Comment: Yes. Something about unable to create a constant value of type char.

Comment: Try `u.firstname + " " + u.lastname` then :-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight thanks all working now! You can answer and I can mark as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *From the comments:* [I get an error] about unable to create a constant value of type `char`.

The problem with your expression is the way you add a space in between the first and second string. EF knows how to translate string concatenation to SQL, but it does not know how to translate `+` between a field of string type and space `' '`, a constant of type `char`.

Replacing concatenation expression with `u.firstname + " " + u.lastname` will fix the problem, because the space `" "` is now a string literal, not a `char` constant.

Answer (score 0):

Replace code with below code that will help you i think.

```
 using(var ent = new testEntities)
    {
        ent.Contacts.Where(u => (u.firstname + " " + u.lastname).contains(searchString))
    }
```

Comment: I don't think changing the `" "` to `' '` will make any difference. If so, *why* does it?

Comment: It does but dasblinkenlight actually got the answer right first!

Comment: @PiotrStulinski but i do not read of comment of dasblinkenlight.. sorry but i also i try for you